# addEntry does not work in Vaadin FullCalendar add-on

Tags: java, calendar, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I've written logic that adds an event inside a Vaadin FullCalendar but it does not work.

This is my code so far. By clicking "update" I should be able to add an event to my calendar:

```
InMemoryEntryProvider<ResourceEntry> entryProvider = new InMemoryEntryProvider<>();
calendar.setEntryProvider(entryProvider);
  
//update or remove a calendar entry
HorizontalLayout entryControlsLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
entryControlsLayout.setSpacing(true);
entryControlsLayout.setAlignItems(Alignment.BASELINE);
Entry entryCustom = new Entry();
Select<String> selectTitle = new Select<>();
DatePicker datePickerStart = new DatePicker("inzio");
DatePicker datePickerEnd = new DatePicker("fine");
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker("Select Time");
TimePicker timePickerEnd = new TimePicker("Select Time");
datePickerStart.setValue(LocalDate.now());
datePickerEnd.setValue(LocalDate.now());
timePicker.setValue(LocalTime.now());
timePickerEnd.setValue(LocalTime.now());
selectTitle.setLabel("Ordina Come");
selectTitle.setItems("Primo più recente", "Rating: high to low", "Rating: low to high", "Price: high to low", "Price: low to high");
selectTitle.setValue("Primo più recente");
entryCustom.setTitle(selectTitle.getValue());
entryCustom.setColor("#ff3333");
entryCustom.setStartEditable(true);
entryCustom.setStart(datePickerStart.getValue().atTime(timePicker.getValue()));
entryCustom.setEnd(datePickerEnd.getValue().atTime(timePickerEnd.getValue()));
Button updateButton = new Button("Update", e -> {
   entryCustom.setTitle(selectTitle.getValue());
   entryCustom.setStart(datePickerStart.getValue().atTime(timePicker.getValue()));
   entryCustom.setEnd(datePickerEnd.getValue().atTime(timePickerEnd.getValue()));
   calendar.getEntryProvider().asInMemory().addEntries(entryCustom);
});
Button removeButton = new Button("Remove", e -> {
  calendar.getEntryProvider().asInMemory().removeEntries(entryCustom);
});
entryControlsLayout.add(selectTitle, datePickerStart, datePickerEnd, timePicker, timePickerEnd, updateButton, removeButton );
```

and this is the style setting that I have:

```
calendar.setSizeFull();
calendar.setLocale(Locale.ITALIAN);
calendar.setFirstDay(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
calendar.setTimezone(Timezone.UTC);
calendar.setNowIndicatorShown(true);
calendar.setNumberClickable(true);
calendar.setWeekNumbersVisible(false);

HorizontalLayout calendarLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
calendarLayout.setSizeFull();
calendarLayout.addClassName("calendar-layout");
calendarLayout.add(calendar);

add(entryControlsLayout, topControlsLayout, calendarLayout);

monthViewButton.addClickListener(event -> calendar.changeView(CalendarViewImpl.DAY_GRID_MONTH));
weekViewButton.addClickListener(event -> calendar.changeView(CalendarViewImpl.TIME_GRID_WEEK));
dayViewButton.addClickListener(event -> calendar.changeView(CalendarViewImpl.TIME_GRID_DAY));

setSizeFull();
setSpacing(true);
```

I've been trying [to follow this](https://github.com/stefanuebe/vaadin_fullcalendar/wiki/FullCalendar-Examples) but it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: It looks ok on the surface, but maybe there's some subtle error. Have you tried hard-coding the date and time of the event?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Also your subject states "addEntry", but
in your code only is a call to "addEntries". Typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i understand better.
to create a event by clicking on a date on the calendar:

```
 private void showEditorDialog(Entry entryOnClick, boolean isNew, FullCalendar calendar) {
            InMemoryEntryProvider<Entry> entryProvider = calendar.getEntryProvider().asInMemory();

            Dialog editorDialog = new Dialog();
            VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
            TextField titleField = new TextField("Titolo Evento");
            titleField.setValue(entryOnClick.getTitle());
            layout.add(titleField);

            // Save button click listener
            Button saveButton = new Button("Salva", event -> {
                entryOnClick.setTitle(titleField.getValue());
                if (isNew) {
                    entryProvider.addEntry(entryOnClick);
                } else {
                    entryProvider.refreshItem(entryOnClick);
                }
                editorDialog.close();
                entryProvider.refreshAll();
            });

            // Cancel button click listener
            Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancella", event -> {
                entryProvider.removeEntry(entryOnClick);
                editorDialog.close();
                entryProvider.refreshAll();
            });

            layout.add(saveButton, cancelButton);
            editorDialog.add(layout);
            editorDialog.open();
        }
```

Then i created a separate class to handle the toolbar:

```
 protected SubMenu initEditItems() {
    SubMenu calendarItems = addItem("Crea Evento").getSubMenu();

    MenuItem addRecurringItems;
    MenuItem addSingleItem;
    InMemoryEntryProvider<Entry> entryProviderToolbar = calendar.getEntryProvider().asInMemory();

    if (onSamplesCreated != null) {
        addSingleItem = calendarItems.addItem("Crea singolo Evento", event -> {
        //event.getSource().setEnabled(false);

        // Create a dialog to collect user input
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        // Create Vaadin components for user input
        TextField titleField = new TextField("Titolo Evento");
        titleField.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);

        DatePicker startDatePicker = new DatePicker("Inizio Evento");
        startDatePicker.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);

        TimePicker startTimePicker = new TimePicker("Orario Inizio Evento");
        startTimePicker.setValue(LocalTime.MIN);
        DatePicker endDatePicker = new DatePicker("Fine evento");
        endDatePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        TimePicker endTimePicker = new TimePicker("Orario Fine Evento");
        endTimePicker.setValue(LocalTime.MAX);

        // Add components to the layout
        layout.add(titleField, startDatePicker, startTimePicker, endDatePicker, endTimePicker);

        // Create save and cancel buttons
        Button saveButton = new Button("Salva", saveEvent -> {
            //validate required fields
            if (titleField.getValue().isEmpty() || startDatePicker.getValue() == null) {
                Notification.show("Pervafore inserisci tutti i campi obbligatori", 3000, Notification.Position.MIDDLE);
                return;
            }
            // Create a new entry with the user's input
            Entry entry = new Entry();
            entry.setStart(startDatePicker.getValue().atTime(startTimePicker.getValue()));
            entry.setEnd(endDatePicker.getValue().atTime(endTimePicker.getValue()));
            entry.setTitle(titleField.getValue());

            // Add the entry to the calendar and refresh the view
            entryProviderToolbar.addEntry(entry);
            entryProviderToolbar.refreshAll();
            onSamplesCreated.accept(Collections.singletonList(entry));
            Notification.show("Added a single entry");

            // Close the dialog
            dialog.close();
        });
        saveButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

        Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancella", cancelEvent -> {
            dialog.close();
        });

    // Add buttons to the layout
    layout.add(saveButton, cancelButton);

    // Add layout to the dialog and open it
    dialog.add(layout);
    dialog.open();
});
```

this is how you can create an event outside and inside the calendar